# How to use TextInputLayout with EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

In my application I want use `TextInputLayout`, and for this I write below codes.
But after run application, not show any stroke for `Edit Text`!
Just show me empty `Edit text`!
**My result image :** 
[image: Result image]

**My codes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.login.send_phone.SendPhonePage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sendPhone_logo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_150mdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150mdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30mdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <!--Phone number-->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/signInFrag_phoneInpLay"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15mdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15mdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15mdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15mdp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30mdp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1mdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sendPhone_logo">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/signInFrag_phoneEdt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/insertYourPhoneNumber"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="11"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10mdp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10mdp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorLightGray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10mdp"
            app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/ic_outline_phone" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I used this dependency : `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'` with this style     `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">`

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText` and remove the `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`.

Comment: thanks my friend, I change my codes with your help. now show me stroke, but my language is RTL and my hint is RTL language. but when move this hint text to above, show empty space in left of EditText. but I want show this hint empty space i right of edittext! how can it?